# Get a time of first transaction for each day from stock data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Recently I got a csv file with transactions our company made on different markets/instruments. My data set consist of more than 500k rows.

Here is my data sample without irrelevant (in this moment) columns:

```
Market  Price   Quantity
Time            
2019-01-01 09:42:16 Share   180.00  5.0
2019-01-01 09:44:59 Share   180.00  10.0
2019-01-01 09:46:24 Share   180.00  6.0
2019-01-01 09:47:21 Share   180.00  5.0
2019-01-01 09:52:19 Share   180.00  10.0
2019-01-01 09:52:19 Share   180.00  5.0
2019-01-01 09:52:19 Share   180.00  5.0
2019-01-01 09:57:37 Share   180.01  10.0
2019-01-02 10:03:43 Share   235.00  10.0
2019-01-02 10:04:11 Share   235.00  10.0
2019-01-02 10:04:19 Share   235.00  10.0
... ... ... ...
2019-05-13 10:06:44 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:45 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:45 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:49 Share   234.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:49 Share   234.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:54 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-14 09:50:56 Share   230.00  10.0
2019-05-14 09:53:31 Share   229.00  10.0
2019-05-14 09:53:55 Share   229.00  5.0
2019-05-14 09:53:59 Share   229.00  3.0
2019-05-14 09:54:01 Share   229.00  2.0
2019-05-14 09:54:07 Share   229.00  3.0
2019-05-14 09:54:16 Share   229.00  2.0
```

I already converted Time column to pandas datetime.

Although I was able to obtain some desired statistics I got stuck on finding time of first and last transaction for each day.

```
Expected OUTPUT:

2019-03-12 08:43:23    Share(name) 248  10
2019-03-12 16:48:21    Share(name) 250  20
```

Well I don't have problems with getting this in Excel but considering fastly growing number of data I would rather use pandas and python for this purpose.

I am assuming that some combination of groupby and resample methods could be solution but I have no idea how to apply them correctly to my dataframe.

Any thoughts and comments will be appreciated.

Thanks to **Ben Pap** I got result using:

```
dbs.groupby(dbs.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[0:1,-1:0]])
```

Here is another question I came up. What function I suppose to use to get max value of time of first transaction. So in other words which day market starts at the latest?

Comment: You should not modify your post for extra question. Instead, open a new post.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.day).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[0:1, -1:0]])
```

This will give you the first and last of each day as long as your dates are ordered.

Comment: Since 'Time' is my index column I got an error. I made small change:

dbs.groupby(dbs.index.day).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[0:1, -1:0]])

However now I got output as first transaction in 2019-01-01 and last at 2019-05-14 as one group
2019-01-01 09:42:16  180.00 5.0
2019-05-14 10:30:03 198.50 15.0



dbs.groupby(dbs.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[0:1,-1:0]]) - this worked as expected. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1:

`groupby` followed by `apply`

```
new_df = (df.groupby(df.index.floor('D'))
            .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0,-1]])
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         )
new_df
```

## Option 2:

`groupby` followed by `agg` and `stack`

```
new_df = (df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.floor('D'))
            .agg(['first','last'])
            .stack(level=1)
            .reset_index(drop=True)
            .set_index('Time')
         )
```

Output:

```
                    Market  Price   Quantity
Time            
2019-01-01 09:42:16 Share   180.00  5.0
2019-01-01 09:57:37 Share   180.01  10.0
2019-01-02 10:03:43 Share   235.00  10.0
2019-01-02 10:04:19 Share   235.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:06:44 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-13 10:11:54 Share   233.00  10.0
2019-05-14 09:50:56 Share   230.00  10.0
2019-05-14 09:54:16 Share   229.00  2.0
```

In any case, you may want to do `drop_duplicates` afterwards in case there are days with only on transaction.

Comment: In your Option 2 solution didn't get a time of transactions.

Comment: @1001001 Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Now it works as expected. Great thanks! Do you have any ideas for this extra question regarding the latest start of the market?

Comment: `.reset_index().groupby(df.index.date).Time.min().max()`. You can do either on `df` or `new_df`. But like I said, next time, please open a new question.

Comment: When I tested this option it unfortunately returns min() but only for first or last day in my dataset. 
`maxDF = new_df.reset_index().groupby(new_df.index.date).Time.min().max()`

Comment: What is ` latest start of the market` then? And do you see my point of new question, this is way beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: By latest start I meant the latest time of first transaction and the output would be the date when this occurred. But I got your point for new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your index in datetime format you can use the method `resample()`:

```
df['Datetime'] = df.index
df.resample('D').agg(['first', 'last']).stack().set_index('Datetime')
```

Result:

```
                    Market   Price  Quantity
Datetime                                    
2019-01-01 09:42:16  Share  180.00       5.0
2019-01-01 09:57:37  Share  180.01      10.0
2019-01-02 10:03:43  Share  235.00      10.0
2019-01-02 10:04:19  Share  235.00      10.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but what I am most interesting is time of transactions. Price and Quantity are also very valuable informations but in this particular case what I need the most is time.

Comment: @1001001 Ok. Now I have fixed it.